# Grunt Concat Task, how to ignore all .min.js files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following grunt concat task. How can I make concat ignore all minified files? This doesn't work.

```
concat: {
    js: {
        src:  [ 
            '<%= globalConfig.bar %>', 
            '<%= globalConfig.foo %>/*.js', 
            '<%= globalConfig.foo %>/!*.min.js', 
            '<%= globalConfig.fooLib %>/*.js', 
            '<%= globalConfig.fooLib %>/!*.min.js'
        ],
        dest: '../../foo/fooCombined.js'
    },
    css: {
        src: ['<%= globalConfig.foo %>/*.css'],
        dest: '../../foo/fooCombined.css'
    }
},
```

*This also doesn't work:*

```
'<%= globalConfig.fooLib %>/(*.js && !*min.js)'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone briefly explain what the syntax `<%= ` means?

Comment: They are used for templating.. See here http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
concat: {
  js: {
    src:  [ 
        '<%= globalConfig.bar %>', 
        '<%= globalConfig.foo %>/*.js', 
        '<%= globalConfig.fooLib %>/*.js', 
        '!**/*.min.js'
    ],
    dest: '../../foo/fooCombined.js'
  },
  css: {
    src: ['<%= globalConfig.foo %>/*.css'],
    dest: '../../foo/fooCombined.css'
  }
},
```

Negate or `!` is placed at the beginning of a valid pattern to produce the opposite effect. Patterns are processed in order, so placing a negated pattern that you wish to exclude at the end, will do the trick.

See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns for more info.

Comment: I got it to work by doing this. `!<%= globalConfig.fooLib %>/*min.js'` The link helped. Thanks.

Comment: Take care of the order. You need to specify the ignored files / folders at least. I guess javascript is running from bottom up, so this works in this way...