# Ignore array of files with Grunt

Tags: javascript, arrays, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

If I have an array of files in my Gruntfile like so:

```
var jsFiles = [
  'src/js/abc.js',
  'src/js/def.js'
]
```

How can I exclude each file in this array without having to prepend `!` to each file? This pattern doesn't seem to work for me:

```
!jsFiles
```

I would also love to be able to do `!<%= project.jsFiles %>` where `<%= project.jsFiles %>` is an array of files.

There are a number of similar questions on Stack Overflow but not one that addresses ignoring an array of files, from what I can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt Concat Task, how to ignore all .min.js files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622914/grunt-concat-task-how-to-ignore-all-min-js-files)

Comment: That answer does not address how to ignore a whole array of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Negate array of files:**

If your want to negate a list of files, like this:

```
var jsFiles = [
  'src/js/abc.js',
  'src/js/def.js'
];
```

You can create a function to add the "!":

```
function addErase(jsFiles){
  var arr = [];
  jsFiles.forEach(function(element){
    arr.push("!" + element);
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Then you can transform your array:

```
var jsFileErase = addErase(jsFiles);
//   ['!src/js/abc.js',
//   '!src/js/abc.js']
```

**If you want to put the list in the package.json:**

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "jsFiles":[
    'src/js/abc.js',
    'src/js/def.js'
  ],
  ...
```

Inside Gruntfile.js:

```
var project = require('./package.json');
var jsFiles = project.jsFiles;
```

Then you can negate all the files with the function addErase

**Negate all element inside a folder:**

If you want to negate all the elements inside a folder, you need to put "!" before the path and "/**/*" at the end of the path:

Example:

```
var jsFile = '!src/js/**/*'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great solution. The only catch I can see is if using it like: `['**/*', jsFileErase]` to include everything first then ignore the files inside the array. We run into an issue because `jsFileErase` is an array itself.

Comment: You  can use a library like underscore an use a function like http://underscorejs.org/#flatten for that

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.